# Joint CDF of linear transformed random vector

Tags: probability

I have a really annoying problem. I am trying to determine the joint cdf

$P(X_1 \leq t_1, X_1+X_2 \leq t_2)$

for two iid Exp$(\lambda)$ variables $X_1,X_2$, and I find the joint density to be

$f(x_1,x_2)=\lambda^2 e^{-\lambda x_2}$

which apparently does not depend on $x_1$, except for $0\leq x_1 \leq x_2$. So how do I set up the integral so the limits are correct?

I tried

$\lambda^2\int_0^{t_2} \int_0^{x_2}e^{-\lambda x_2}dx_1dx_2$

but its not right. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is
$$P(X_1<t_1\,,\,X_1+X_2<t_2)\,=\,\int^{t_1}_0dx_1\int^{t_2-x_1}_0dx_2\,f(x_1,x_2)\,=\,\\=\,\int^{t_2}_0dx_2\int^{t_1-x_2}_0dx_1\,f(x_1,x_2)$$

Comment: how do you get that? It doesn't seem correct however, the answer should be $1-e^{-\lambda t_1}-\lambda t_1e^{-\lambda t_2}$...thanks

Comment: Well, this is the definition of the left-hand side, given $f$ as pdf. There is not much to change here. Did you check you got $f(x_1,x_2)$ right? What you wrote as solution is **not** right. The reason is that it shows the wrong dependency on $\lambda$, given the $f$ you provided.

Comment: I'm pretty sure its correct, I just applied a linear transformation to the joint density. Anyway, if $x_2 \eq x_1$, doesn't it make sense to integrate $x_2$ over the interval $(x_1,t_2)$? This yields the result i provided. Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: You are being too lose with your statements. For instance, "integrate $x_2$ over the interval $(x_1,t_2)$ has no meaning, as $x_2\in\mathbb{R}$. That said, I oversaw the $t_1$ in the solution you provided. That factor assures the right dimensionality of the expression. Finally, once more, the expression I wrote for the probability is correct for all $f$. This is so *by definition* of $P(x_1<t_1,x_1+x_2<t_2)$.

Comment: One more thing, notice that you can interchange the integrals. See my answer.